# Why does ResourceBundle in null (in application with FXML and JavaFX 2.0)

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I have an application written on JavaFX (with using of FXML). I'm trying to internatiolize my app. I was trying to do it like it is described in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17411_01/javafx/2.0/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm#CHDFJDAE).

I have a property file with text like this: **submit=Войти**

I have a button, described in FXML:

```
<Button id="button1" fx:id="submit" layoutX="69.0" layoutY="200.0" onAction="#loginFired" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="97.0" text="\%submit" />
```

Property file and fxml file are in the same directory.

But my button do not have a text, i expect it to have, it is written "%submit" on it, but not "Войти".
Then i've tried to do something like in [this one tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization)
In my intialize method i have suh code:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle resources) {
    if(resources == null)
        System.out.println("error");
}
```

and it gives me an "error" message to the log.

So, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text="\%submit"
```

`\` character means escape the next character which is `%` in this case, resulting to be written as "%submit" in the output. So correct usage is `text="%submit"`.

If you are loading FXML file using the FXMLLoader then do not forget to set the resource as well:

```
fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.MyBundle", locale));
```

look again the [JavaFX 2 and Internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10143392/682495) for full example.
Also check the result of `ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.MyBundle", locale)` for not being null.

Comment: As this one statement *if(resources == null)* shows, my ResourceBundle resources is null. And a question is what am i doing wrong that it is null?

Comment: Either you are not setting the resource through `fxmlLoader.setResources()` or `ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.MyBundle", locale)` is returning null. There maybe other reasons of course.