# What is "automatic injection of location and resources properties into the controller" in JavaFX?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, javafx

In the description of [`Initializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) interface it is said:

> NOTE This interface has been superseded by automatic injection of
>   location and resources properties into the controller. FXMLLoader will
>   now automatically call any suitably annotated no-arg initialize()
>   method defined by the controller. It is recommended that the injection
>   approach be used whenever possible.

The question is: how to "suitable annotate" methods? I find only one annotation -- `@FXML`. Are there any others?

Comment: suzan @fxml tag shows that the variable or controller are design in fxml...for designing better fxml way may be this help you `stackoverflow.com/questions/19523341/adding-a-tilepane-instantiated-in-java-files-to-fxml`

Comment: I'm surprised the answer has not yet been accepted. :)

Answer (score 17):

The answer is [located here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm):

> In JavaFX 2.1 and earlier, controller classes were required to
>   implement the Initializable interface to be notified when the contents
>   of the associated FXML document had been completely loaded. In JavaFX
>   2.2, this is no longer necessary. An instance of the FXMLLoader class simply looks for the initialize() method on the controller and calls
>   it, if available. Note that, similar to other FXML callback methods
>   such as event handlers, this method must be annotated with the @FXML
>   annotation if it is not public.
>
> It is recommended that developers use this approach for new
>   development. The Initializable interface has not been deprecated, but
>   might be in a future release.

**EDIT**

After more research, I can now now provide an SSCCE demonstrating how to inject a resource bundle into a controller with annotations. Please note that this SSCCE contains slight modifications from the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization).

Here is the SSCCE:

**com/stackexchange/stackoverflow/_20107463/MyController.java:**

```
package com.stackexchange.stackoverflow._20107463;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MyController {

  @FXML 
  private Label label;

  @FXML private ResourceBundle resources;

  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    label.setText(resources.getString("key1"));
  }

  // Or if you don't want to use @FXML you could do:
  //public void initialize() {
  //  label.setText(resources.getString("key1"));
  //}
}
```

**com/stackexchange/stackoverflow/_20107463/MyView.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>

<BorderPane fx:controller="com.stackexchange.stackoverflow._20107463.MyController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <top>
    <!-- This label's text will be set by the controller -->
    <Label fx:id="label"/>
  </top>
  <center>
    <!-- This label's text will be taken from the bundle automatically -->
    <Label text="%key2"/>
  </center>
</BorderPane>
```

**com/stackexchange/stackoverflow/_20107463/BundleDemo.java:**

```
package com.stackexchange.stackoverflow._20107463;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBoxBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BundleDemo extends Application {

  private Stage stage;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    stage = primaryStage;
    Button btnEN = new Button();
    btnEN.setText("English");
    btnEN.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        loadView(new Locale("en", "EN"));
      }
    });

    Button btnKG = new Button();
    btnKG.setText("Español");
    btnKG.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        loadView(new Locale("es", "ES"));
      }
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(20);
    root.getChildren().add(HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(10).style("-fx-background-color: gray").padding(new Insets(5)).children(btnEN, btnKG).build());
    root.getChildren().add(new StackPane());
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void loadView(Locale locale) {
    try {
      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

      fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.stackexchange.stackoverflow.bundles.MyBundle", locale));
      Pane pane = (BorderPane) fxmlLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("MyView.fxml").openStream());
      // replace the content
      StackPane content = (StackPane) ((VBox) stage.getScene().getRoot()).getChildren().get(1);
      content.getChildren().clear();
      content.getChildren().add(pane);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

**com/stackexchange/stackoverflow/_20107463/MyBundle_en.properties:**

```
key1=Name Surname
key2=How are you?
```

**com/stackexchange/stackoverflow/_20107463/MyBundle_es.properties:**

```
key1=Apellido
key2=Que tal?
```