# Language of JavaFX color picker

Tags: java, javafx, color-picker

Is there a way to change language of `ColorPicker`'s texts such as "Custom Color...", "Current Color", "New Color", "Hue", "Saturation", "Brightness", "Opacity", "Save", "Use", "Cancel"?

[image]

Comment: For translation of standard system window on the other languages is some information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45980313/3937190

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Below answer is for those who need some more *exotic* language. If you use one of those: `de, es, fr, it, ja, ko, pt, sv, zh` @sergey-grinev provided sufficient answer.

---

I came up with two solutions. Both rely on `properties` file. You can create your own based on examples found in `com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/` in `jxfrt.jar` provided with JRE.

All examples will use polish Locale (`new Locale("pl", "PL")`) which is not built-in.

---

## Solution 1

Create JAR file with following structure (change suffix accordingly)

```
com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls_pl_PL.properties
```

and place it in

```
<path_to_JVM>/lib/ext
```

That's it.

I'm not sure what the license says about placing custom files in `com.sun.*` packages, so here's another solution.

## Solution 2

Create `properties` file like above, but you can name it whatever and place it wherever you want. Let's say it will be

```
path/to/my/resources/polish.properties
```

Create two classes - `ResourceBundle.Control` and `ResourceBundleControlProvider` ([read more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/serviceproviders/resourcebundlecontrolprovider.html#create-implementations-of-resourcebundle.control)) like this.

```
public class CustomLocaleFxResourceBundleControl extends ResourceBundle.Control {
    static final String FX_BASE_NAME = "com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls";
    private static final Locale MY_LOCALE = new Locale("pl", "PL");

    @Override
    public String toBundleName(String baseName, Locale locale) {
        if (FX_BASE_NAME.equals(baseName) && MY_LOCALE.equals(locale))
            return "path/to/my/resources/polish"; // without extension

        return super.toBundleName(baseName, locale);
    }
}
```

```
public class CustomLocaleFxResourceBundleControlProvider implements ResourceBundleControlProvider {
    private static final ResourceBundle.Control MY_RESOURCE_BUNDLE_CONTROL = new CustomLocaleFxResourceBundleControl();

    public ResourceBundle.Control getControl(String baseName) {
        if (CustomLocaleFxResourceBundleControl.FX_BASE_NAME.equals(baseName))
            return MY_RESOURCE_BUNDLE_CONTROL;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Compile those classes and put them in JAR file along with your resource and `META-INF` folder. `META-INF` folder should have following structure

```
META-INF/services/java.util.spi.ResourceBundleControlProvider
```

`java.util.spi.ResourceBundleControlProvider` is a text file which only line is path to `ResourceBundleControlProvider`  class. In our case it's just

```
CustomLocaleFxResourceBundleControlProvider
```

Complete JAR put in

```
<path_to_JVM>/lib/ext
```

Comment: This is my first time making such changes and I'm having some troubles. I'm using Eclipse(jdk 1.8.40) and can't find properties file that you mentioned above.

Comment: In `<jdk_installation_directory>/jre/lib/ext` there is `jfxrt.jar`. Copy it, change extension to `zip`, unpack and look in the directory mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I retrieved needed properties file and made changes to it. I created both CustomLocaleFxResourceBundleControlProvider and CustomLocaleFxResourceBundleControl in bin\com\my folder (where mainApp is), also put there controls_pl.properties file. But I am confused about "Compile those classes and put them in JAR file along with your resource and META-INF folder. META-INF folder should have following structure". I just can't understand what exactly to do. I'm at begginer level with Java and can't yet understand all.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Eclipse is compiling program on the fly. Should I compile those two classes manualy? Can't understand in which jar should I put these classes. In the same jar, from which I took properties file? If I look at Java FX DDK, that I'm using, it has org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_1.0.0.jar in which META-INF with only maven folder in it. Should I create META-INF/services/java.util.spi.ResourceBundleControlProvider?

Comment: You can manually prepare desired directory structure ([screen](http://i.imgur.com/vzdXGHO.png)). Enter `toJar` folder, select all, right click, add to ZIP archive (depends on your installed software). After that change extension of result `.zip` to `.jar`. You can pick `.class` files from `bin` directory in eclipse project. In your situation move them first to default package - declared package and path within JAR must be the same.

Comment: Thank you fro screenshot! It helped a lot. Should I put jar file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext or go to properties for project and add jar to jdk library?

Comment: As stated in my answer `<path_to_JVM>/lib/ext`, so in your situation `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/ext`.

Comment: Added everything and restarted eclipse. After running program I got exception: Could not initialize class java.util.ResourceBundle. [screen](http://s019.radikal.ru/i636/1504/80/0e96499e8a60.jpg)

Comment: I've decided for now to use first solution, but later I will definitely figure out what I could possibly do wrong in second one) Thank you for all your explanations.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use one of predefined locales, e.g. add next line before creating ColorPicker:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH);
```

You'll see next UI:

[image: french color picker]

Comment: It works for French. But what to do, if I need to create ColorPicker for other languages like Russian or Estonian? Tried to use ` Locale dLocale = new Locale("ru"); Locale.setDefault(dLocale);` , but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3629015 lol, Russian and Estonian are two languages I speak besides English :) Take a look at 3ph3r answer in this case.

Comment: почему все всегда забывают про русских?(

Comment: @sinedsem Я не забыл, смотрите мой ответ здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/45979456/3937190

Comment: @AndreiKrasutski thanks, but I've already become disappointed about JavaFX and desktop java development