# JavaFX Dialogs : add a custom locale

Tags: localization, javafx-8

I would like to use the JavaFX 8  dialogs in NL locale. Unfortunately, this language is not provided by the JDK.
I tried to create the _nl file in the resources of my project (at the same directory than the bundles of the JDK). When a call the ResourceBundle from a class in my project, all is working as expected. But when the ResourceBundle is called by JavaFX dialogs, my _nl file is not taken into account.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213034/javafx-8-localization-of-dialogs-internal-elements) a workaround using a listener on the expanded property. But I would like a fix for all my dialogs (info, error, ...).

Is there a way for JavaFX dialogs to take into account "custom" bundle files ?

Thank you

Comment: I do not see an easier approach to your problem. Nevertheless, you can try creating a custom Dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any other way than creating my own dialogs. But it's awful not to be able to add another language to this built-in dialogs.

Comment: Below answer is for those who need some more exotic language [post by 3ph3r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612570/language-of-javafx-color-picker/29616661#29616661)