# JavaFX dialog internationalization in java module based project

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, internationalization

I would like to ask for a help with internationalization of buttons in JavaFX built in dialogs.

Translations for buttons are available in https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources
There are some other countries and also fallback to English variant.

From code POV translatiosn are loaded by this class: https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/ControlResources.java

```
public final class ControlResources {

    // Translatable properties
    private static final String BASE_NAME = "com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls";

    public static String getString(String key) {
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle(BASE_NAME).getString(key);
    }
}
```

To add custom translation I would create new **controls_xx.properties** file in resources of my application under following package: *com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls*.

The issue is that "java-modules" do not allow to have one package in multiple modules.

What are the possibilities to load custom translations for JavaFX dialogs?

Note: disabling "java-modules" is not an option.

Thank you

EDIT: I'm aware of this thread: [Javafx Internationalization with custom language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838804/javafx-internationalization-with-custom-language)

Comment: Perhaps something to ask on the [openjfx-dev mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.org/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

Comment: This kind of functionality is [documented well for the standard JDK and Swing distributions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk21-suported-locales.html#jfc).  I think that allows customization of locales via service provider interfaces such as [java.util.spi](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/spi/package-summary.html) and java.text.spi. If so, the service provider would allow you to add new locales and still work with modules.  But I don't know where it is equivalently documented for JavaFX (or if documentation or spi classes exists).

Comment: I checked the JavaFX 21 documentation and it doesn't define any services for modules at all.  Perhaps a service to allow addition of new language localization resources for built-in JavaFX platform dialogs (or other text), could be added in the future via a feature request (again perhaps something to discuss on the openjfx-dev mailing list).

Comment: An alternative to `--patch-module` (see my answer below) _might_ be to simply modify the `javafx.controls` JAR file and insert your properties file. This would be done as part of your project's build process. Though I would prefer using `--patch-module`, as that seems more "official" to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, the `javafx.controls` module would make use of the [`ResourceBundleProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/spi/ResourceBund) SPI. This would let your own module provide an implementation that would find the custom resource bundles. But since JavaFX does not make use of said SPI (as of version 21.0.1), and since split packages are not allowed, another solution is needed.

One option is to make use of `--patch-module`. For instance, if you wanted to add translations for Russian ([which is not one of the provided languages in JavaFX 21](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/tree/jfx21/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources)), then you would create the properties file in the correct package:

```
com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls_ru.properties
```

And place that in some directory; let's say that directory is named `bundles` for this example. Then at run-time, you would use the following option:

```
--patch-module javafx.controls=bundles
```

<sup>**Note:** This assumes `bundles` is relative to the working directory. If that's not the case, then use the proper relative path or an absolute path.</sup>

---

## Example

Here's a full example using Java 21.0.1, JavaFX 21.0.1, and Gradle 8.5.

### Source Code

**module-info**

```java
module app {
  requires javafx.controls;

  exports sample to
      javafx.graphics;
}
```

**sample.Main**

```java
package sample;

import java.util.Locale;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.of("ru"));

    var dialogBtn = new Button("Show dialog");
    dialogBtn.setOnAction(
        e -> {
          var alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
          alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
          alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
          alert.setContentText("This text is intentionally English.");
          alert.show();
        });

    var root = new StackPane(dialogBtn);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Demo");
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

### Bundle Properties File

**controls_ru.properties**

```
Dialog.yes.button = Да
Dialog.no.button = Нет

Dialog.confirm.title = Подтверждение
Dialog.confirm.header = Подтверждение
```

<sup>**Note:** There are many more properties you'd have to set to properly add a language, but these are all that were needed for this example.</sup>

These translations were taken from Google Translate. I have no idea how accurate they are.

| English | Russian |
| --- | --- |
| Yes | Да |
| No | Нет |
| Confirmation | Подтверждение |

### Gradle Files

**settings.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "app"
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.1.0"
    application
}

group = "sample"
version = "0.1.0"

application {
    mainModule = "app"
    mainClass = "sample.Main"
}

javafx {
    modules("javafx.controls")
    version = "21.0.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks {
    named<JavaExec>("run") {
        jvmArgs("--patch-module=javafx.controls=${file("bundles")}")
    }
}
```

### Project Structure

```
<PROJECT_DIRECTORY>
│   build.gradle.kts
│   settings.gradle.kts
│
├───bundles
│   └───com
│       └───sun
│           └───javafx
│               └───scene
│                   └───control
│                       └───skin
│                           └───resources
│                                   controls_ru.properties
│
└───src
    └───main
        └───java
            │   module-info.java
            │
            └───sample
                    Main.java
```

Note the `bundles` directory is not under `src/main/resources`. You don't want to package this in your own module, as doing so will cause a split-package error. Unfortunately, this means you have to find a way to deploy `bundles` alongside your application. I *assume* doing this would be relatively easy using a tool like `jpackage`, but I haven't tried it.

### Output

From executing the Gradle `run` task.

[image: screenshot of running application]

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand, but here is a workaround if I understand you correctly.

This is tedious: Find the button using `lookupButton`.

**Example**

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
        System.out.println("default Locale: " + defaultLocale.toLanguageTag());
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("sed.work.internationalizationexample.resourcebundle.main", defaultLocale);
        
        Button btnAlert = new Button("Press for alert!");
        
        btnAlert.setOnAction((t) -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.setTitle(resourceBundle.getString("alertTitle"));
            alert.setHeaderText(resourceBundle.getString("alertHeaderText"));
            alert.setContentText(resourceBundle.getString("alertContentText"));

            Button okButton = (Button)alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
            okButton.setText(resourceBundle.getString("alertOkBtnText"));
            Button cancelButton = (Button)alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.CANCEL);
            cancelButton.setText(resourceBundle.getString("alertCancelBtnText"));
            
            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
                // ... user chose OK
            } else {
                // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
            }
        });

        
        //var label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(btnAlert), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**Output**

[image]