# Is en_EN a valid language locale

Tags: java, javafx, internationalization

In the example for internationalization at [JavaFX 2 and Internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization)
the locale passed is resolved as en_EN. Is it even a valid locale?

Comment: en = language English, UK = country United Kingdom. Now England is not separately listed in java. You might however introduce a variant `en_UK_EN` for own translations for non-Scottish, non-Wales things like "jolly". Non found keys then default to the predefined en_UK.

Comment: `en_GB` is correct language code, not `en_UK`! I had issues with `en_EN ` when localizing dates (date was not formatted as european date).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Enabled Locales for java.util and java.text Functionality](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html#util-text) for a list of all supported locales by Oracle's JDK 8 and the JRE 8.

The language tag `en-EN` is not listed.

That's because the string given as the country code ("EN") is not an assigned [ISO 3166 alpha-2 country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Current_codes) (see [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), "country (region)").

A list of all 2-letter country codes defined in ISO 3166 can be retrieved with `Locale.getISOCountries()`.