# JavaFX8 w/manual layout: any automated localization / internationalization methods?

Tags: javafx, localization, internationalization, javafx-8

JavaFX 8 scenes using .fxml files allow keying and automatic resolution of text strings. Most of the web discussion/examples of localization show this technique.

Is there any easy or similar method to use when manually constructing/coding JavaFX scenes? I am unable to find sources.

Comment: There's nothing specific in the JavaFX API, you would just use a [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) in the usual way. There's a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html) as part of the standard Oracle Java tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ResourceBundle's

Take a look at this Question:

[JavaFX 2 and Internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization)

Its good explained there

Comment: Oh how hilarious - the op there asks almost the exact question I ask above, but in a *comment* for the first answer. Thanks!