# How to set Locale to a TextField

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Im working on a Application  which i need to Enter Data in multiple languages , I know how to change locale in swing like this

```
 txt.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("en", "US"));
```

I want to do the same in Texfield in Javafx

Let me know how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX 2 and Internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization)

Comment: @Sedrick Thanks for the reference but for me user have to enter data which will be stored in database