# How to Add Multiple keys in Single Node in javafx internationalization

Tags: java, javafx, internationalization

I reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization)

Single key works.

```xml
<Label text="%key2"/>
```

But now I want to add multiple keys as value of attribute.
Is there any way to **concat** keys?

I also tried with `%key1`, like:

```xml
<Label text="%key1%key2"/>
<!-- OR -->
<Label text="%key1,%key2"/>
```

but it does not work. How to do that?

Comment: Could you explain what's your issue that make you to add multiple keys in the same node ? as far as I know we use %key to define multiple languages for the same node.

Comment: i want to concat Text using two keys

Comment: in the second language change the value of the "key2" => ",value2" :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the main goal of `%key` is internalization ,I mean it refers to many languages from different properties files.You can add multiple keys content in the same node in java code by this way :

```
myLabel.setText(bundle.getString("key1") + bundle.getString("key2"));
```

Comment: can we concat text from FXML File only.? not from controller..!

Comment: Each node has unique key.So as my knowledge you can not define many keys for one node.