# JavaFX 11 International Language Support -- All languages?

Tags: java, internationalization, javafx-11

I am trying to develop a JavaFX 11 application where I need to display [Amharic/Geez/Ethiopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%27ez_script)  alphabets. I've tried all the suggestions on StackOverflow (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization)), but all characters are displayed as a bunch of empty rectangles on the UI/stage/scene. Looks like JavaFX 11 does not support complex writing systems yet (according to the [Java 11 locale support docs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java11locales-5069639.html)!). Any ideas?

[Title of JavaFX app correctly displays the characters -- but not in the body. See attached screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b0kE.png)

Comment: Are you using a font that includes glyphs for the code points you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was not using the right font. Problem solved. Thanks, @Jim Garrison.