# JavaFX: How to Change the Locale in JFXDatePicker

Tags: java, javafx, locale, jfoenix

I would like to change Locale of JFXDatePicker to my own custom Locale like into Cyrillic more precisely Uzbek Language. I searched google but there were no good tips about what to do.
[image]

in this DatePicker, I would like to see my own custom string instead of пн,мар 19 and so on. How I could modify JFXDatePicker into my own Locale?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization) may help you?

Comment: this tells about multiLanguages

Answer (score 1):

A better late than never answer:

[`JFXDatePickerContent`](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/skins/JFXDatePickerContent.java) is the class which is responsible for formatting all cells, days, and months in `JFXDatePicker`. 
There is an instance of `JFXDatePickerContent` inside [`JFXDatePickerSkin`](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/skins/JFXDatePickerSkin.java):

```
JFXDatePicker > JFXDatePickerSkin > JFXDatePickerContent
```

`JFXDatePickerContent` provides this method:

```java
protected Locale getLocale() {
    return Locale.getDefault();
}
```

Although the method looks to be designed to be overridden to return a specific `Locale`, the class has a package-private constructor. And here is the method that returns that content object from `JFXDatePickerSkin`:

```java
@Override
protected Node getPopupContent() {
    if (content == null) {
        content = new JFXDatePickerContent(jfxDatePicker);
    }
    return content;
}
```

The problem is that the `private JFXDatePickerContent content` object is accessed directly (not using this getter method) inside `JFXDatePickerSkin` and that means overriding this method to return another custom `JFXDatePickerContent` (if it were possible) will not make everything work as expected.

**Short Answer:**
Use `Locale.setDefault(Locale newLocale);` (if that's possible in your application).

I am not sure if the Uzbek language has a support for Cyrillic script but this is how it should be done:

```
Locale uzCyrl = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("uz").setScript("Cyrl").build();
Locale.setDefault(uzCyrl);
```

Here is the output after setting the locale for Spanish / Spain:

```java
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es", "ES"));
```

[image: sample output]