# FXML translation feature in fxml file

Tags: java, javafx

I have this object in fxml (among others):

```
  <Label text="Birthday">
        <font>
          <Font size="16.0" />
        </font>
  </Label>
```

I also have this Excel document:

```
Birthday     Date d'anniversaire     День Рождения
```

It contains two translations of the word Birthday.

I need to be able to change the text of the label when in the application in dropdown list another language is chosen. How would I do that? Is it possible to do inside the `.fxml` file?

This is how I load stage from file:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));

scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 500, 400);
```

Comment: You'll probably need to do this in the controller class rather than the FXML.

Comment: How? I already have the whole structure of the app, all of its components inside the FXML file. And many components need to be translated (a lot of rows in Excel)

Comment: Which question?

Comment: When I've translated text in java apps before, I've had the app structure in FXML but then programmatically translated everything in the .java controller class when needed. I can post an example if you'd like.

Comment: Yes I would appreciate it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization

Comment: @parsecer if you use an @ it will notify somebody. There are a couple answers in there, it seems like you can create a resource bundle, then switch the resource bundle to change the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, this is just an example of how I have done translation in the past. This does not do translation within the FXML.
Snippet of FXML (frmCalendar.fxml)

```
<Label fx:id="lblTitle" text="Title"/>
```

Snippet of Controller Class (CalendarController.java)

```
if (!Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en")) {
    lblTitle.setText(TranslationManager.translate("en", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(), lblTitle.getText());
}
```

Snippet of TranslationManager.java

```
public class TranslationManager {
    public static String translate(String langFrom, String langTo, String text){
        //Here is where you would read your excel file and return the text in the desired language.
    }
}
```

Here's a great [question about reading excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file) if you are not familiar with that process.