# JavaFX internationalization not working in jar file

Tags: javafx

I developed an application in JavaFX that supports the English and Arabic languages.

Support for both languages works fine in NetBeans, however, when I run the jar file, the Arabic language does not work (see the screenshot).

How can I fix this problem?

[image: screenshot]

---

Note, the menu bar portion does work fine in the Arabic language because I have this line of code that uses the system menu bar.

```
final String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

if (os != null && os.startsWith("Mac")) {
    myMenuBar.useSystemMenuBarProperty().set(true);
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: thanks guys i fixed my problem by adding arabic font to my application

Comment: Great, you can add that as a [self-answer if you wish](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I edited Uluk's answer to the [reference question for the JavaFX internationalization topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization) to include advice on ensuring appropriate fonts are available for an internationalized application.